# Visual Studio 2015 Community with CPLEX 12.7 samples do not run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, cplex

When I try to open one of the sample models inside samples folder(C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\cplex\examples\x64_windows_vs2015\stat_mdas) and try to build it says build is successful but when I want to debug it setting a breakpoint to a line I got the following lines:

```
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio127\opl\bin\x64_win64\cplex1270.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'admipex1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x62c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3414 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3ea4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12884] admipex1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Visual Studio 2015 is not supported by any CPLEX version yet.

Try using other Visual Studio versions like 2013 or earlier.

Follow this guide here:

http://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-configure-ms-visual-studio-to-use-ibm-cplex-concert/